# How to understand the categorization of traffic from utm parameter values from externally clicked URLs in Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: analytics, traffic, url-parameters, universal-analytics

[This page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#campaign-params) features the six utm parameters you can send from an external link to a page via Google Universal Analytics.

And I'm still a little bit confused on the relations between these parameters for a click on a URL to my website:

[image: Diagram featuring Google Universal Analytics URL Parameters as I understand them...and as I do not understand them]

[Click Here to see the larger version on imgur](https://imgur.com/p5eessp) - Click it again after the link to see the larger version.

To explain the diagram above,

- Inside the blue rectangle:

  - White rectangles utm parameter values I think I understand
  - Red rectangles indicate utm parameter values I'm having issues understanding or more specifically categorizing the values they should have.
  - Rectangles, red or white, represent utm parameters and their possible example values:

    - **utm parameter names:** Listed in bold at on the header of the rectangle.
    - **utm possible values for that parameter:** Listed in non-bold under the rectangle.
- Outside the blue rectangle:

  - White notes indicate the definition of the parameter as I understand it from [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#campaign-params).
  - Yellow notes with the string **"WTF"** in them indicate questions I have about parameter names whose definition I find unclear, and are connected to them via a dotted arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTM Trackig is very useful, because it's made for you and it's up to you. Of course Google learns about good practice and explains all of this params. But finally you choose what tracking best suits to your site.

Keep in mind that clarity and cohesion it's your goal.

In company which I working for:

a) **utm_source** - means simply source of the traffic (e.g. google, trovit, criteo, msn)

b) **utm_medium** - type of ad form/payment (e.g. banner, organic, rtb, cpc, link)

c) **utm_campaign** - name/id of campaign, ad form or placement (e.g. 1200x600, welcome_msg, premium, sidebar)

d) **utm_content** - for A/B tests in e-mail marketing (e.g. photo1, 2h_delay)

BUT... it's suits for us :)

===

You've asked about e-mail tracking. It depends on yours communication via e-mail. We do it this way:

a) utm_source = brand_name

b) utm_medium = e-mail

c) utm_campaign = newsletter OR reminder (our service)

d) utm_content = name_of_newsletter OR reminder_params